# How to set value in array helper Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to set value of array helper in Yii 2 as id (primary key of database).
But when I use it shows me 0,1,2,3,.. not its real id number.

Here is my array helper code:

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'username',
  array_merge(array(''=>' '), ArrayHelper::map(Experts::find()->all(), 'id', 'username'))) ?>
```

How can I access real value of primary id??

When I use other parameter it works correctly but when I use id it shows number from 0 to up : |

Comment: Use 'prompt' attribute to set default option. <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'username',
  ArrayHelper::map(Experts::find()->all(), 'id', 'username'), ['prompt' => '--- select'] ) ?>

Comment: no i mean can not set each value as id of database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_merge` renumbers numeric array keys. Use `+`.

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList(
    $model, 
    'username',
    ['' => ' '] + ArrayHelper::map(Experts::find()->all(), 'id', 'username')
) ?>
```